# Найти индекс вхождения

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Дана задача:
дается две строки needle и haystack, верните индекс первого появления иглы в стоге сена или -1, если игла не является частью стога сена.

Моя идея:

Топаем по строке пока не встретим первое вхождение, как нашли запоминаем индекс и начинаем считать сколько раз совпадают символы и если число совпадений равно длине "иглы" тогда выходим и возвращаем индекс

Код:

```
private static int indexOfFirstOccurence(string haystack, string needle)
        {
            int shift = 1;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < haystack.Length; i += shift)
            {
                int matchCount = 0;
                if (haystack[i] == needle[j])
                {
                    index = i;
                    shift = i;
                    while (haystack[shift] == needle[j] && j < needle.Length)
                    { 
                        /* вижу что ещё i надо увеличивать чтобы шагать дальше по строке 
                         
                         
                         */
                        matchCount++;
                        j++;
                        shift++;
                        if (matchCount == needle.Length)
                        {
                            return index;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

помогите сделать так чтобы работало, в своей реализации кучу "приколов" нашёл когда пытался организовать смещение i на расстояние которое уже просмотрел в строке

Comment: Там ещё для разных символов разные смещения поиска делают в зависимости от того, повторяются они или нет, если облом и искать надо заново. Я забыл как этот алгоритм называется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут поможет просто два цикла, один вложенный в другой.

Я решал [задачку](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-index-of-the-first-occurrence-in-a-string/description/) как то так, c небольшим трюком, но идея понятная я думаю

```
public class Solution
{
    public int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        if (haystack.Length == 0 && needle.Length == 0) return 0;
        if (needle.Length == 0) return 0;
        
        int di = 0;
        
        for(int i=1; i<needle.Length; i++)
        {
            if (needle[i] == needle[0]) break;
            di = i;
        }
        
        for(var i=0; i<(haystack.Length-needle.Length + 1); i++)
        {           
            for(var j=0; j<needle.Length; j++)
            {               
                if (haystack[i + j] != needle[j])
                {
                    if (j > di) i+= di;
                    break;
                }
                
                if (j == needle.Length-1) return i;
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Простейший вариант без приколов будет выглядеть как то так

```
public class Solution
{
    public int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        if (haystack.Length == 0 && needle.Length == 0) return 0;
        if (needle.Length == 0) return 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < (haystack.Length - needle.Length + 1); i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < needle.Length; j++)
            {
                if (haystack[i + j] != needle[j]) break;
                if (j == needle.Length - 1) return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Если интерес чисто академический, и интересно почитать про эффективные алгоритмы поиска подстроки, можно начать отсюда [Алгоритм Кнута — Морриса — Пратта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

А стандартным методом вспользоватся не хотите?

```cs
haystack.IndexOf(needle)
```

Comment: никак нет, хочу написать свой собственный велосипед и радоваться жизни